# PSR names for Intermediate Directory

Tags: php

I can't find anything on the internet about PSR rules citing some canonical naming convention for intermediate directories:

```
Use OtherVendor\OtherPackage\Some_Other_0001\BazClass;
```

Is it possible to use underscore in `\Some_Other_Package\` or is there a rule that only StudlyCase can be used:

```
Use OtherVendor\OtherPackage\SomeOther0001\BazClass;
```

I understood that the rule was only set for the name of classes and methods.
and what about the namespace declaration and import?

**Update:**

moddle document say that can exist some exeption to implement prefix like that (that use undersocorer) but preventing of old version usage: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Coding_style#Namespaces

but i not find other reference and this other doc say that have some diference with PSR-12 and PSR-1 around Scope not naming Convention...

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Coding_style#Scope

Comment: [Here](https://www.php-fig.org/bylaws/psr-naming-conventions/) naming conventions, directories should be named CamelCase

Comment: @Arman Actually, nothing described on this page indicates something especially about intermediary directory ... aesthetically they used in the example the code camelCase; in other StudlyCase.

Comment: @Arman moddle document say that can exist some exeption to implement prefix like that: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Coding_style#Namespaces but i not fine other reference and this other doc say that have some diference with PSR-12 and PSR-1 around Scope not naming convention... https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Coding_style#Scope